# Training custom classifiers using trainCascadeObjectDetector

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, signal-processing, video-processing

Is there any good documentation about training custom classifiers different from [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/train-a-cascade-object-detector.html) provided by MathWorks. I already asked [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8373/training-custom-classifiers-using-traincascadeobjectdetector) in dsp.stackexchange but there weren't good enough answers, so don't judge me.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you only interested in working with cascaded classifiers in Matlab?

Comment: @Max: For now, yes I do, but other references could help too...